# presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession Shows error if link is itunes

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

```
   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               FB_APPID, @"app_id",
                               @"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/guess-this!/id657293868?mt=8", @"link",
                               @"Guess This", @"name",
                               @"I'm playing Guess This for iOS. Join my leaderboard!", @"message",
                               @"Guess This is a social puzzle game, just match the pictures to a word or phrase.", @"caption",nil];


[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:[FBSession activeSession] parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {

}];
```

Hello,

Above is the code I am using to post to facebook. If I use any link other than itunes server it works fine, I tried with many links(google, yahoo etc.) it works perfectly, but only for the itunes links I am getting the error as below.

Can anyone please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8SQw.png

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but after some research I started to get the solution myself. 
And the solution is using of https://bitly.com/